# Modify $select to allow for searching in php

Tags: php, sql

How do I modify my `$select` function to allow searching with a database when the customer types in the search text and clicks "Search"?  I'd also like to be able to type in the form field, and PHP automatically updates the page with the form data dynamically and to be able to define the field to search upon in the database!

This is letting me view my customers table:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC");
<?php
        if (!$select->num_rows) {
            echo '<p>', 'No records', '</p>';
        }else{
        ?>
            <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                while ($row = $select->fetch_object()) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->FName;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->LName;?></td>
```

Comment: `Bonus Points`: How will you give us those? :P

Comment: Once I get enough "reputation", I will go back through answers from helpful people, and upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you might try putting your opening `<?php` **before** rather than **after** the first line of code... :-)

Then you simply modify your code to get the values from your HTML form - I will assume that your search term is named `q` kind of like this:

```
Search: <input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
```

Then your PHP script doing the searching will change the query to something like this:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$_REQUEST[q]%' OR LName LIKE '%$_REQUEST[q]%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

If you are entered "Sam" that will end up with a query that looks like this:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%Sam%' OR LName LIKE '%Sam%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Do note that I am showing you the simplest version by simply constructing the query. In fact you should NEVER do this with user-supplied data. Instead, you should prepare and then bind and then execute your statement.  This is not just filler at the end of the answer - it's really important.  But while you are testing you may want to see how it works just be forming a string as above.

To answer your "BONUS POINTS" - you can update the current page by simply including your search form on the same page as the PHP script which displays the results. Then you only process your PHP code if the submit button has been pressed.  Your whole script (in a very simple form) might look like this:

```
Search: <input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['search'])) {
    # do your query
    # loop through the results, printing them off in appropriate HTML
}
```

To answer your "BONUS BONUS" points, you would probably set up a pull-down ("select" in HTML) where the values of the options were the actual field names and the display was a human-readable form of that.  If your select had the name "field_name" then you would modify your query like this:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE $_REQUEST[field_name] LIKE '%$_REQUEST[q]%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Do note that you cannot prepare/bind to a column name, so you will just have to be very careful to validate that field very exactly (probably checking that it exists in a list of acceptable values).

Comment: One thing I should mention, I already have the current table being viewed on the same page.  How can I flush that table out, or alter it on the fly with the search statement?

Comment: Each time you press "submit" the page re-loads from scratch. That's how HTML forms work. If you were populating a temporary table in your DB then you would need to think about how to flush it, but since you're just using a normal SELECT query you should have no problems at all.

Comment: I have the current select clause checking for empty rows, and if rows are not empty, it returns with the html code with viewing the table via "else".  How do I add an "else" within the "else" that takes place when you search?  For instance :  If (rows empty) echo no records, else (print table data), else (look at search form data, and accept data for refresh upon click submit)

Comment: Sorry - doesn't make sense. `if ... else ... else ...` -- how would you ever get to the 3rd block of code? "else" means "in all other cases" - so how are you going to get a case that isn't part of "all other cases"? In any event, it sounds like you need a new question entirely to document what you're doing and what's not working.